# How to get MTU L2 and MTU L3 values from interface?

Tags: networking, mtu

I need to get both l2 and l3 MTU values from interface. I can use `ip a show eth0` or `ifconfig eth0` but they show only one MTU and I don't know which one l2 or l3.

Comment: Traditionally the MTU is IP's (so, one L3 protocol's) idea of how big of a unit of data it can pass down to L2. So it's a concept regarding the *interface* between those two layers. So if it's about L3 interfacing to L2, does that count as L3 or L2 in your way of thinking about it?

Comment: @Spiff, MTU L3 size does not always define the size of MTU L2. My interface can make fragmentation of network packet (L3) into smaller size frames (L2), so I could define both, e.g. MTU L3 = 2000 and MTU L2 = 1000